# To set Video Src at runtime

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html, video, html5-video

i am using a video element of html5 to support the video in different browser as

```
<video id="ss" controls="controls" tabindex="5" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" data-setup="{}" poster="my_video_poster.png">
     <source src="Videos/2.webm" type='"video/webm" codecs="vp8, vorbis"' >
      <source src="Videos/2.ogv" type='"video/ogv" codecs="theora, speex"'>
      <source src="Videos/2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
     </video>
```

i am require to set a `SRC` of video at the click of the button.
i am having a problem of how to set a Video `src` at the run time in asp.net. thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#ss').attr('src','Videos/2.ogv');
var video = $('#ss').get(0);
    video.load();
    video.play();// if you want to make it play after source changed
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#Button1").click(
                              function () {
                                  
                                  $('#ss').attr('src', 'Videos/1.mp4');
                                  var video = $('#ss').get(0);
                                  video.load();
                                  video.play();
                                  alert("sadfcx");


                              });
         });
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

Please, use jQuery to change source of video at runtime.

Please refer link fore more details.

Try `$("#ss video")[0].load();` after you changed the `src` attribute

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/change-youtube-and-yahoo-video-links-to-embedded-players